# Unite segments algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

We have a list of correct segments [a;b] (a <= b).
Need to get a new list with united segments if they are crossed.
 For example: [1;3], [2;4], [7;8] => [1;4], [7;8]. 
I have an idea: first of we make list of borders and for each border we know is it left or right, then we sort it ASC by border value and then by left or rith(left borders go first) . 
 The idea is to go through this list and:
1) As left border we take the first we meet 
2) Right border will be determined like the following:
 We have a counter = 0 and when we meet left border then ++counter, when it's right  so --counter and when counter == 0 then we take current border as right.

 And so on until end of list
What do you think about this algo? Maybe other ideas?

Comment: What happens if segments touch rathr than cross? I.e: [1,3], [3,4], [7.8] => ?

Comment: thanks for pointing out! In that case we can check if right border equals left and if so just continue loop. So condition for taking right border is COUNTER == 0 AND currentRight != next Left. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your idea is in general right. More algorithmic description:

Make an array with pairs for all segment ends `(a or b; aux = +1 for a, -1 for b)`

Sort array by coordinate
(using `aux` as secondary key in case of tie: put -1 before +1 if touched segments should not unite and vice versa in other case)

Make `Count = 0`

Run through array, adding `aux` to `Count`

Value of `Count` in every moment corresponds to the number of opened segments

When `Count` becomes non-zero, open output segment
When `Count` becomes zero, close output segment

```
   (1, 5), (2,6)
array 
   (1; 1), (2; 1), (5;-1), (6;-1)
count 
0    1       2         1      0
     ^                        ^
    start                    end
```